# YoloNas slower than Yolov8

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolov8, yolonas

as showed in the plot YoloNas-l should run much faster than YoloV8-l
[image: Inf times]
But when i am testing it my self in google-colab i am getting different results!

```
#installing pakcages
!pip install super-gradients==3.1.2
!pip install ultralytics
!pip install pytorch_quantization==2.1.3
!pip install boto3

import super_gradients
from ultralytics import YOLO
import time

!mkdir images
%cd ./images
!wget https://qph.cf2.poecdn.net/main-129957940_34140400692_36_1.png
!wget https://deci-pretrained-models.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_images/beatles-abbeyroad.jpg
!wget https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/view-tiger-animal-wild_23-2150374850.jpg
!wget https://www.fonedog.com/images/photo-compress/image-compressor-image.jpg
!wget https://static.addtoany.com/images/dracaena-cinnabari.jpg
!wget https://qph.cf2.poecdn.net/main-129957940_34139995188_34_1.png
!wget https://qph.cf2.poecdn.net/main-129957940_34139020340_37_1.png

%cd /content/images
import glob
types = ['*.png','*.jpg']
images =[]
for typ in types:
  for image in glob.glob(typ):
    images.append('/content/images/'+image)
    print('/content/images'+image)
nas_ult = NAS('yolo_nas_l.pt')
results = nas_ult.val(data='coco8.yaml')
yolov8 = YOLO("yolov8l.yaml")
yolov8 = YOLO("yolov8l.pt")
nas_inf= 0
nas_res=[]
v8_inf = 0
v8_res=[]
for image in images:
  nas_ult_preds = nas_ult(image,imgsz=640)
for image in images:
  yolov8_predictions = yolov8(image,imgsz=640)
for image in images:
  start = time.time()
  nas_ult_preds = nas_ult(image,imgsz=640)
  end = time.time()
  nas_res.append((nas_ult_preds, end-start))
  nas_inf += end-start
  start = time.time()
  yolov8_predictions = yolov8(image,imgsz=640)
  end = time.time()
  v8_res.append((yolov8_predictions, end-start))
  v8_inf += end-start

print('V8 time:',v8_inf)
print('NAS time:',nas_inf)
```

and this is my resualt

**YoloNas-l time: 0.4496428966522217**

**YoloV8-l time: 0.399261474609375**

why its happening?

Comment: some one said it may be for the input size different. as i found YoloNAS input size is 640*640 and i have changed yoloV8 input size to 640 and yoloV8 is faster than before now !

Answer (score 0):

Could You try on a file of 100 images, you will see the difference in speed in a case like this, yolo-nas takes a much longer time to call the model in the first run but after that, it is faster, but not that much of a difference.
if you are looking for a fast model use the yolov8 Tensorrt it is said that it will give you x4 speed than the regular.pt model

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35416299)

Answer (score -1):

Its all about `super_gradients` VS `ultralytics!` just use yoloNAS with

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i want to use yoloNAS with ultralytics it shows that i need Super_gradients to be installed! so I think its just calling Super_gradients and  ultralytics is doing nothing here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)